Slack Markdown: Most text is only partial hyperlinked instead of full
I have this Cloud Function that posts to Slack, some text is fully hyperlinked but the majority is only partial and I don't know why. The full bug title should be hyperlinked. Can anyone help me debug it? For example, these are fully hyperlinked:

Fix portfolio Dockerfile path


Profiler for A: The user can still change chains

Yet many aren't like this:

Overview > Historical Token Portfolio [and other widgets]: Changing
time period filters completely resets the token selection>

Code:
async function generateSummary(groupedBugs) {
    try {
        const openai = new OpenAI({
            apiKey: OPENAI_API_KEY
        });

        const currentDate = new Date();
        const oneWeekAgo = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        
        let formattedBugs = `*Weekly Bug Recap: ${oneWeekAgo.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' })} - ${currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' })}*\n_______________________________\n\n`;
        
       // Separate known features and unknown features
       const knownFeatures = {};
       let unknownFeatures = [];

       for (const [feature, bugs] of Object.entries(groupedBugs)) {
           if (feature === 'Unknown Feature') {
               unknownFeatures = bugs;
           } else {
               const mainFeature = feature.split(':')[0].trim();
               if (!knownFeatures[mainFeature]) {
                   knownFeatures[mainFeature] = [];
               }
               knownFeatures[mainFeature].push(...bugs);
           }
       }

       // Format known features
       for (const [feature, bugs] of Object.entries(knownFeatures)) {
           formattedBugs += `*${feature}*\n`;
           bugs.forEach((bug, index) => {
               const fullTitle = bug.title.replace(/^BUG\s*::\s*/i, '').trim();
               formattedBugs += `${index + 1}. <${bug.url}|${fullTitle}>\n`;
           });
           formattedBugs += '\n';
       }

       // Format unknown features at the bottom
       if (unknownFeatures.length > 0) {
           formattedBugs += `*Unknown Feature*\n`;
           unknownFeatures.forEach((bug, index) => {
               const title = bug.title.replace(/^BUG\s*::\s*/i, '').trim();
               formattedBugs += `${index + 1}. <${bug.url}|${title}>\n`;
           });
       }


        const prompt = `Format the following bugs by feature using Slack's markdown syntax:
        - Preserve the existing bold text, underlines, and hyperlinks
        - Do not use code blocks, quote blocks, or any other additional formatting
        - Do not add any additional information
        - Ensure the output matches the input format exactly but make sure hyperlink covers full text, not partial!
        - The output should be plain text with Slack markdown, not wrapped in any blocks

        Here's the bug summary to format:

        ${formattedBugs}`;

        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: "gpt-4o-mini",
            messages: [{ "role": "user", "content": prompt }],
        });

